# Visual Studio how to find files in "solution folder"

Tags: visual-studio

I have created a virtual folder in visual studio using "Add" > "New Solution Folder" and then added a lot of projects in it, is there any way I could find text in all projects in that particular virtual folder i.e. "the solution folder" rather than in any other location options VS provided such as "Current Project", "Entire Solution" and "All Open Documents"? because I have a big solution, but a small "solution folder", so I want to quickly get the search result.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer...

If you are ready to pay, I strongly suggest you Resharper. I personally can live without it.

With this tool, you have great options for searching.

I recently face the same problem; searching in the solution explorer for a specific folder instead of types.

Here is the function to search:

[image]

And then type your folder...

[image]

After I select the folder in the dropdown list, the specified folder is selected in the solution explorer.